# Why is the site currently in "read-only" mode?

Tags: support, read-only-mode

What sort of maintenance is going on? When will it end, and why is meta working fine?

And don't think this is a duplicate of the older questions asking the same thing. I've looked at the status websites (StackStatus and Twitter) and would like the developers to provide more information, as I don't have a Twitter account. Also, this question is dedicated to this specific outage, not of general outages.

Comment: Datacenter move (a big one). See https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=%23stackdcmove&src=typd

Comment: Things are being switched back on site by site.

Comment: How are people posting on SO during the maintenance?

Comment: @connor: I suspect the API has been available for mobile posts. I just received an inbox message on my iPhone, for example.

Comment: And we are back out of RO mode!

Comment: A quick note - following the end of the outage, I had several messages "stuck" in my inbox, i.e., no matter how many times I read them they showed up again every time I moved to a new page.  Logging out and then restarting my browser appears to have fixed it, so if anyone else runs into this, that's the first thing to try.

Comment: Seems to be back in RO again, unable to log into main site for the last 30 minutes at least, mobile site works fine in the meantime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange moved relocated their NYC datacenter elsewhere; the network was hosted from the Oregon failover datacenter for a few days.

We are seeing the final stages of the move back to the new datacenter. Sites are switched back on one by one, I believe, and Meta.SO (as well as Meta.SE) were among the first to come back out of read-only mode.

Mobile apps use the API, which is also already online it appears. New posts and comments appearing are probably posted through that.

You *should* be able to follow most of the story via a [Twitter search for #StackDCMove](https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=%23stackdcmove&src=typd).

Comment: I wonder why they don't host in many different data centers?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: I guess the architecture of the site doesn't lend itself to such a setup; the sites are heavily database driven.